# xcodebuild test for especific Target/Scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xcodebuild, xcode-ui-testing

I'm facing with this error:

command:
`xcodebuild test -scheme Exclusive -destination "platform=iOS"`

result:
`xcodebuild: error: Scheme Exclusive is not currently configured for the test action.`

My scenario: 3 targets, 3 schemas. One target for each theme. So I need to run UI test for each target.

What I'm doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

**EDIT:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the `Exclusive` scheme doesn't include a test target. You can add/remove them by double-clicking on the scheme name in the Manage Schemes window.

Then click the `+` in the bottom to add your testing target(s).

[image]